# How do I include both a left and right sidemenu in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I include both a left side menu, triggered by left navicon, and a right side menu, triggered by right navicon using the ionic framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually is very simple. You just need to have two side-menus, and two corresponding buttons that will toggle the side menus.

E.g :

```
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
                <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
                </ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-nav-view name="appContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
                <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-cart ng-controller='CartController'></ion-cart>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
        <ion-side-menu side="right">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
                <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-cart ng-controller='CartController'></ion-cart>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
```

You can refer to the complete codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYvjze)

Comment: Please can you tell me how to add sidemenu in tab app of ionic?

Comment: You can include your tab container in the **<ion-side-menu-content>** tag

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic4 the markup changed a bit, but is also still simple.

```html
<ion-split-pane>
   <!-- left content here -->
  <ion-menu side="start">
    <ion-content>
      <app-profile></app-profile>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

   <!-- right content here -->
  <ion-menu side="end">
    <ion-content>
      <app-other-user-profile [user]="them"></app-other-user-profile>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-content main>
   <!-- main window content here -->
  </ion-content>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Comment: I couldn't generate different content from the left and right icon. I have the ion-header tag(where are my two buttons for opening side nav) in the home component. and ion-menu code in app component. always opens left menu content. @kneeki

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple you can create `sidemenu` app and open menu file and copy tag which content left and put them at same as left menu and modified its name `right` to `left`

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
                    Login
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
                    Search
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
                    Browse
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    Playlists
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Right</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
                    Login
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
                    Search
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
                    Browse
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    Playlists
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```